# Sort NSDictionary keys according to NSArray elements

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `NSDictionary` filled with many objects. I have sorted the keys in a desired pattern and now I have the keys only in a new `NSArray`. How to apply the changes so the order of the elements in the array to be reflected in the dictionary? 
For ex. `NSArray -> ["D" , "B" , "A" , "C"]` this order I want to apply to the keys in the dictionary.

```
NSDictionary -> {{"A" : <something>} , {"B" : <something>} , {"C" : <something>} , {"D" : <something>}}
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't sortable. Please clarify what you mean. I get that you have the keys in an array but it's unclear what you are trying to do once you have the keys in the array.

Comment: Then I want to sort or make new NSDictionary in that order.

Comment: As was stated, dictionaries have no concept of order. Keep your key array is whatever order you want. You can use that array to access values from the dictionary in your desired order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.  You iterate over the keys in the array and then pull out the data from the dictionary.

```
for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
    id value = dictionary[key];
    // do something...
}
```

If you need ordering you might consider using NSOrderedSet or rolling your own data structure to do this.  For example, I have created data structures that use both NSIndexSet and NSDictionary to provide key/value storage with faster sorted enumeration.